# Parsing a string into a hash structure in perl

Tags: perl, parsing, hash

I have the following string:

```
$str = "list
    XYZ

    status1    : YES
    value1     : 100
    status2      : NO
    value2     : 200
Thats all";
```

I want to convert it into a hash using a function which takes this string as input and returns a hash with `status1` as *key* and `YES` as *value* for example.

How to do so?
And how to reference the returned hash?

Comment: The question is not clear on what the boundaries are.  Should we assume the first non-space token after a colon is a value, and stuff not on a line containing two tokens separated by a colon should be ignored?

Comment: The last question about referencing the returned hash has nothing to do with the parsing question and [is trivial](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut): `my %data = parse($str); my $data_ref = \%data;`

Comment: an alternative to get a reference to the returned hash might be `my $data_ref = {parse($str)};`

Comment: I am using parse($str) but the perl script is asking me what function is parse? Do I have to include a specific Perl lib from cpan? Please guide.

Comment: It says undefined subroutine parse.

Answer (score 15):

Like always, **there's more than one way to do it**. Here come five.

## Pure regular expressions (YEAH!)

I think this is the coolest one. The regex returns a list of all captures which is exactly the list we want to initialize the hash with:

```
my %regex = $str =~ /(\S+)\s*:\s*(\S+)/g;
```

## Iterative

This is the most straightforward way for most programmers, I think:

```
my @lines       = split /\R/ => $str;
my %iterative   = ();
for (@lines) {
    next unless /(\S+)\s*:\s*(\S+)/;
    $iterative{$1} = $2;
}
```

Nothing to explain here. I first [`split`](http://p3rl.org/split) the string in lines, then iterate over them, leaving out lines that don't look like `foo : bar`. Done.

## List processing

Writing everything as a big list expression feels a little bit hackish, but maybe this is interesting to learn more ways to express stuff:

```
my %list =  map     { /(\S+)\s*:\s*(\S+)/ and $1 => $2 }
            grep    { /:/ }
            split   /\R/ => $str;
```

Read from *right to left*: Like in the example above we start with splitting the string in lines. [`grep`](http://p3rl.org/grep) filters the lines for `:` and in the final map I transform matching line strings in a list of length two, with a key and a value.

## List reducing

Non-trivial use-cases of [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aUtil)'s **reduce** function are very rare. Here's one, based on the list approach from above, returning a hash *reference*:

```
my $reduced = reduce {
    $a = { $a =~ /(\S+)\s*:\s*(\S+)/ } unless ref $a;
    $a->{$1} = $2 if $b =~ /(\S+)\s*:\s*(\S+)/;
    return $a;
} grep { /:/ } split /\R/ => $str;
```

## State machine

Here's a funny one with regex usage for white-space separation only. It needs to keep track of a state:

```
# preparations
my $state   = 'idle';
my $buffer  = undef;
my %state   = ();
my @words   = split /\s+/ => $str;

# loop over words
for my $word (@words) {

    # last word was a key
    if ($state eq 'idle' and $word eq ':') {
        $state = 'got_key';
    }

    # this is a value for the key in buffer
    elsif ($state eq 'got_key') {
        $state{$buffer} = $word;
        $state          = 'idle';
        $buffer         = undef;
    }

    # remember this word
    else {
        $buffer = $word;
    }
}
```

Comment: That awkward moment when you realize you can't upvote more than once.

Comment: Actually thought about downvoting everyone else to make up for it.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun (note that I recommend using one of memowe's) here is one that (ab)uses the YAML:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML;

my $str = "list
    XYZ

    status1    : YES
    value1     : 100
    status2      : NO
    value2     : 200
Thats all";

$str = join "\n", grep { /:/ } split "\n", $str;
my $hash = Load "$str\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

$\="\n";

sub convStr {
        my $str = $_[0];
        my %h1=();
        while ($str =~m/(\w+)\s+:\s+(\w+)/g) {
                $h1{$1} =$2;
        }
        return \%h1;
}

my $str = "list
    XYZ

    status1    : YES
    value1     : 100
    status2      : NO
    value2     : 200
Thats all";

my $href=convStr($str);

foreach (keys(%$href)) {
        print $_ , "=>", $href->{$_};
}
```

On running this, I get:

```
status2=>NO
value1=>100
status1=>YES
value2=>200
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  my %hhash;
  my @lines = split /\s+\n/, $str;
          foreach (@lines)
          {
            $_=~s/^\s+//g;
            if(/:/)
            {
            $key=(split(/:/))[0];
            $value=(split(/:/))[1];
            $hhash{$key}=$value;
            }
          }
```